# Sumar Values de Checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Cordial Saludo.

Les comento, tengo unos checkbox dinamicos de php llevados a html con AJAX, lo que quiero es sumarlos, si marco un check sume el value si lo desmarco lo resta.

```
 $.ajax({                
      type: "POST",                 
      url: url2,                    
      data: protocolo,
      success: function(protocolo)            
     {

                                        $('#criteriosprotocolo').html(protocolo).fadeIn();

}
});
```

el ajax funciona bien, porque me trae bien la informacion

este es el ´PHP al que consulta:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

$tiempo = $_POST['tiempo'];



              $sql = "EXEC SP_CONS_PROTOCOLO";

              $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);

              if(sqlsrv_execute($stmt)){

                echo "<hr style='border-top: 3px double #8c8b8b;'/>"; 
                echo "<label>PROTOCOLO:</label>";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<br>";

                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

                    $Id = $row['Id_Protocolo'];
                    $Indicador = $row['Indicador'];
                    $Puntaje = $row['Puntaje'];

                    echo "<form name='miform' id='miform'>
                        <div class='form-check'>
                          <label class='form-check-label'> 
                          <input name='id' id='clt' type='checkbox' value=".$Puntaje." onclick='sumar()' /><br>
                            ".$Indicador."                          
                        </div>
                        </form>";
                }


                    echo "<br>";
                    echo " <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='comment'>Observaciones:</label>
                                <textarea class='form-control' rows='3' style='resize:none;' id='obserproto'></textarea>
                            </div >";


                    echo " <div class='form-group'>
                             <label>Total protocolo:</label>
                                 <input type='text' autocomplete='off' class='form-control' id='totalprotocolo' disabled>
                            </div>";        

              }


?>
<style type="text/css">
    input[type=checkbox] {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
</style>
```

y me devuelve unos checkbox con unos value, esos value quiero sumarlos y que dejen de sumar si lo desmarco:

```
        <br>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function sumar(){
    obj = document.miform['id'];
    totalChecks = obj.length;
    totalSumado = 0;
    for( i=0; i<totalChecks; i++){ 
        if( obj[i].checked == true ){
            valor = obj[i].value.split('-');        
            totalSumado = totalSumado + parseFloat(valor[0],10);
        }
    }
    $("#totalprotocolo").val(totalSumado);
}
</script>
```

Quiero resaltar que si quito el while del php por un if, funciona, pero con el while no, y necesito que sea un ciclo

Espero me entiendan y me puedan ayudar, gracias

Comment: ¿Después de traer los datos desde PHP estás llamando a sumar()? Si no lo haces, hasta que no hagas clic en un checkbox no te va a sumar ni restar nada.

Comment: Si pongo un alert me ejecuta la funciona, pero no hace nada

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende muy bien. ¿Qué es lo que muestras exactamente desde PHP? ¿Qué quieres decir exactamente con *quiero que los checkbox sean traidos desde php*? ¿Qué quieres decir con *Asi los devuelvo en el PHP*? Sólo muestra un `input`, no todos los elementos que indicas al principio de la pregunta.

Comment: Edite la pregunta